# In given array of strings, grab only vowel containing words

Tags: ruby

I am new in ruby and learning basics, i am stuck on this for quite sometime.

Tried doing :

```
Str="Hi there buddy, long time no see."

arr=str.split()

vow=["a","e","i","o","u"]

arr.select {|x| x.include? vow}
```

I don't even know what is wrong in this, and why it isn't working..

Comment: `x.include? vow` asks whether the word (a string) `x` contains the array `vow`. You'll agree that it doesn't make sense to ask if a string contains an array. If you want to know if the word `x` contains a vowel that would be `vow.include? x`, but that would be an odd question because all words contain a vowel. There are of course words such as "why" where "y" is the vowel and "y" is not in `vow`. "...vowel containing words" (in the title) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

The [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method is good for this:

```rb
arr = ["first", "second", "nth"]
arr.grep(/[aeiou]/)
# => ["first", "second"]
```

It returns all of the array elements that match the given regular expression; the regular expression `/[aeiou]/` matches any string that contains a vowel.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you need to determine for each word, if any of the vowels are present in that word.

```
arr.select { |word| 
  word.filter { |ch| vow.include? ch } 
}
```

But you only need to if the word contains any vowels, but all of the vowels it contains. Now `word` is a `String`, and doesn't work with `#any?`, but `Array` does, so we flip it around to check if the word contains any vowel.

```
arr.select { |word| 
  vow.any? { |v| word.include? v } 
}
```

You could also use regular expressions to accomplish this:

```
arr.filter { |w| w =~ /\w*[aeiou]\w*/ }
```

Or with the vowels not hard-coded:

```
arr.filter { |w| w =~ /\w*[#{vow.join}]\w*/ }
```